# Rails server not visible on network after Yosemite upgrade to 10.10.3 on WiFi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, networking, osx-yosemite

I have a rails server running on my machine that was available to the local network, everything worked fine and i could access my server from other devices using the local dress 192.168.x.x:3000, after the updating the os to 10.10.3 (i had Yosemite before but i can't remember the version) this no longer works, my firewall is disabled and i've tried to start the server using "rails server --binding=0.0.0.0" but it is still not visible for other devices on the network.

EDIT: i now see that the problem is only when i'm using the WIFI if i connect via a thunderbolt and ethernet everything works fine

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe the wireless is on a different subnet? even if they are on the same network, your machine will have different IPs per interface

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be that the wireless router needed a restart, after I tried everything, restarting the mac (the one on which the server runs) and the devices from which i try to connect to, i restarted the router if for some strange reason it started to work.

Maybe this info it will help others

Answer (score 0):

Works Again!

MacOS Yosemite completly removed ipfw *(IP-Firewall)* and now only uses pf *(Packet Filter)*. So all the default forwarding, we are used to is gone!

To make it work again, I used this great tutorial: [Mac pfctl Port Forwarding](http://salferrarello.com/mac-pfctl-port-forwarding/) from *Sal Ferrarello* and changed it to support usual rails servers. Put it in the terminal and ..
it Works again!

#### Process to Success *(Terminal commands)*

**activate rails port forwarding** *(add more if needed)*

```
echo "
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3000 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3001 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3001
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3002 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3002
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3003 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3003
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3004 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3004
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3005 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3005
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3006 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3006
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3007 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3007
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3008 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3008
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3009 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3009
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3010 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3010
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 4242 -> 127.0.0.1 port 4242
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 9292 -> 127.0.0.1 port 9292
" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

**show current forwarding rules** *(check which rules are active)*

```
sudo pfctl -s nat
```

**stop port forwarding** *(CAREFULL! stops it again!)*

```
sudo pfctl -F all -f /etc/pf.conf
```

.. *I still miss SnowLeopard, live of a dev guy was so easy this days* ..

---

### UPDATE:

this only works until next restart. I tried a lot to get it work automatically, I changed */etc/pf.conf*, I changed the pf daemon .. but nothing works!

So I made my own Daemon which just loads my dev ports on startup, which works great!

**/Library/LaunchDaemons/dev.development.servers.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>dev.development.servers</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/bin/sh</string>
                <string>-c</string>
                <string>
                  echo "
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3000 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3001 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3001
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3002 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3002
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3003 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3003
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3004 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3004
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3005 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3005
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3006 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3006
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3007 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3007
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3008 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3008
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3009 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3009
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 3010 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3010
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 4242 -> 127.0.0.1 port 4242
                  rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 9292 -> 127.0.0.1 port 9292
                  " | sudo pfctl -ef -
                </string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```