# Redirect 192.XX.XX to localhost - OSX Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ip, osx-yosemite

I would like to redirect 192.168.199.128 to localhost on OSX Yosemite. I'm running a Rails server on port 3000 and I would like to access it using localhost:3000/home as well as 192.168.199.128:3000/home.

I understand that iptables was removed in OSX Yosemite and pf is the preferred method of doing port forwarding but I'm unable to get it working.

This appears in /etc/pf.anchors/com.analysis, with a newline below it

```
rdr pass on lo8 proto tcp from any to 192.168.199.128 port 3000 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000
```

Additionally, I added the following line to the end of /etc/pf.conf

```
load anchor "com.analysis" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.analysis"
```

Finally, I started pf with the following command:

```
sudo pfctl -ef /etc/pf.anchors/com.analysis
```

Unfortunately, I still cannot access my rails server at 192.168.199.128:3000/home.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621393/rails-server-not-visible-on-network-after-yosemite-upgrade-to-10-10-3-on-wifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rails server -b 192.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: I would definitely prefer to keep my existing server bindings as that could mess up other parts of my config. Any ideas on how to do it with pf?